# Javascript document.addEventListener is not being called if its used in another package with the same event name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this React hook to notify in case the user clicked outside

```
function useOutsideAlerter(ref: any, callback: () => void) {
    useEffect(() => {
        function handleClickOutside(event: {target: any}) {
            if (!ref?.current?.contains(event.target)) {
                callback();
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [ref, callback]);
}
```

and its using document.addEventListener to get notified when user click on the DOM object,

the same hook is used in two packages in the same web app, according to this hierarchy:

Website => 1st package => 2nd package

the eventListener is not being triggered in 2nd package, and its being triggered in the first package,

I tried to change from document to window in 1st package and it worked, but I need understand the root cause of this bug if someone can help,

thanks

---

debugging details:

its never called in 2nd package, and called once in the 1st package only.

Comment: More debug info is required. Maybe you should try putting some logs in your `handleClickOutside` function to see how many times it has been called. I suspect the function got called twice and the first call interferes with the second call. When you changed the event receiver from `document` to `window`, the call order alsochanged (`document` event triggers prior than `window`).

Comment: its never called in 2nd package, and called only once in 1st package,

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about `handleClickOutside()` but not `callback()`? According to your description, if `handleClickOutside` didn't get called in your 2nd package, either the `useEffect` didn't trigger (not likely), or `useOutsideAlerter()` didn't get called at all in your 2nd package.

Comment: Yes sir, I'm aware what I'm talking about, handleClickOutside is not being triggered in the second package,

Comment: also, the clean up callback inside the useEffect inside the 2nd package didn't get triggered, so I know for fact that the listener is there not removed, and the handleClickOutside  is not triggered